# Comparing list with another list items and returning it if it has similar items

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class Object1 {
  final String id;
  List<Object1list> lists = [];

  Object1({this.id, this.lists});

class Object1list {
  final String id;
  final String item;

  Object1list({this.id});
}


List<String> searchlist = ['object1','object2','object3'];
```

What i want to do is I want to search "object1list" items for "any" matches with "searchlist" items and
return it as contain function but I don't know how, something like:

```
return ???.contains(???)
```

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below function will help you to get matched items:

```
bool doSearch(List<String> searchlist, List<String> lists) {
  List<String> matched = [];
  for (String s in searchlist) {
    if (lists.contains(s)) {
      matched.add(s);
    } 
    //else {
    //  return false;  // Uncomment these lines if you want "lists" to contain all searched items
    //}
  }
  return matched.length > 0; // This for 0 or more items matched
}
```

Comment: i need to return it as boolean as .contains is a bool function. You wanted me to return List<String> here,can you fix that please?

Comment: @umarbeyoglu the answer has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

Other ways:

```
import 'package:enumerable/enumerable.dart';

void main() {
  final result1 = searchlist.isNotEmpty
      ? searchlist.distinct().length == searchlist.length
      : false;
  print(result1);

  // OR

  final result2 = searchlist.isNotEmpty
      ? searchlist.toSet().length == searchlist.length
      : false;
  print(result2);
}

List<String> searchlist = ['object1', 'object2', 'object3', 'object2'];
```